# ロードバランサーの限界

Tags: network

ロードバランサーは複数のサーバーにリクエストを分散する目的だと認識しているのですが、
そのロードバランサーにもさばけるリクエスト数というのは物理的に存在するかと思います。

その限界というのはどれくらいのものなのでしょうか。

また、ロードバランサーが限界になったとき、どうするんでしょうか。

facebookやtwitterレベルでも限界ってこないものですか?

ちょっと気になったのでロードバランサーについて教えて下さい。

(タグがわからなかったので、とりあえずnginxにしてみました。適切なタグがあればどなたか変えるか教えて下さい。)

Answer (score 9):

ロードバランサの実装方法や利用方法(ロードバランス手法)によって異なるので、一般論として言える「限界値」はありません。

性能パラメータとしては

- スループット
- 保持可能セッション数
- SSLの場合暗号化スループット

なんかがあります。

上位機種であれば仕様上10Gbps超に対応できたりしますが、そこまで行くまえに普通は回線スループットやアプリケーションなどいろんなところに限界が来るので、CDNを使ってトラフィックを逃がすとか、アプリケーションレベルで接続先を分散するとかし始めます。するとロードバランサの負担は下がっていきます。

Answer (score 5):

ロードバランサーといっても、規模の大小(値段だと40万円～数千万円)がありますから、個々の装置のカタログで確認するしかありません。
例えば、　[F5社(Big-IPというロードバランサ等を作っている)の製品レポート](http://www.f5.com/pdf/reports/F5-comparative-performance-report-ADC-2013.pdf)　のようなものです。

製品の上限よりも、少し低いところに限界値を設定しておき、限界を超えた時には別のサイトに転送したり、「ただいま込み合っています」というようなお断りのページを表示したりといった対応をするように設定されているのが普通です。

各サイトは常時アクセス状況をモニタしておいて、その数倍のアクセスがあっても大丈夫なような装置を用意するなどの対策を取っていますが、ロードバランサ装置が複数故障するといった事故や、DDoS攻撃を受けるといった事態が生じた場合には、どんなに大きなサイトでも限界に達する可能性はあります。

Comment: 普通はロードバランサよりアプリケーションの方が先に限界になります。したがって、いわゆる「ソーリーサーバ(ソーリーページ)」への転送は一般的にはロードバランサの限界ではなくサーバ(アプリケーション)側の限界を基準に行われます。

Answer (score 2):

> その限界というのはどれくらいのものなのでしょうか。

LB業界シェアNo.1のF5ネットワークス社のデータシートです。
http://www.f5networks.co.jp/shared/pdf/BIG-IP-HW-Datasheet.pdf
また、LinuxなどにNginxやLVSをいれてLBとして使った場合、通常１台あたりの性能はハードウェアLBよりも大幅に低いです。
ハードウェアLBにはASICやFPGAでのオフロード機能があるためです。

> また、ロードバランサーが限界になったとき、どうするんでしょうか。

スケールアップ or スケールアウトします。
何のリソースが限界に達したかによりますが、
帯域ならリンク追加、CPUやメモリであればより負荷の低い設定に変更します。
NAT構成 → DSR構成、L7 → L4、パーシステンスをやめる、などなど。

> facebookやtwitterレベルでも限界ってこないものですか?

きます。
なので限界に達しないように日々世界中で研究されてます。
http://yunazuno.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/02/29/090001
日本語だとこのページが参考になります。